# Verify Json response using java

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I would like to get textType and taxAmount from the below Jason response

```
{
"taxExempt": false,
"billingAddress": {
    "addressLine1": "Millers Rd",
    "addressLine2": "",
    "city": "Bengaluru",
    "postalCode": "560052",
    "state": "KA",
    "country": "IN",
    "name": null,
    "email": null
},
"shippingAddress": null,
"billingAccountKey": "20000052",
"invoiceKey": null,
"date": "2018-01-01",
"currency": "AUD",
"taxNumber": "AACCL1660QSD002",
"aggregateTax": true,
"totalTax": 0,
"items": [
    {
        "taxes": [
            {
                "taxType": "GST_IN",
                "taxAmount": 0,
                "taxRate": 0
            }
        ],
        "productFamily": "OpenVoice",
        "productKey": "HDEFSS",
        "referenceProductKey": null,
        "taxCode": "C655",
        "quantity": 1,
        "unitPrice": 100,
        "extendedPrice": 100,
        "overrideTaxAmount": null,
        "LMIEntity": "LogMeIn US"
    },
    {
        "taxes": [
            {
                "taxType": "GST_IN",
                "taxAmount": 0,
                "taxRate": 0
            }
        ],
        "productFamily": "OpenVoice",
        "productKey": "ITFS",
        "referenceProductKey": null,
        "taxCode": "C655",
        "quantity": 1,
        "unitPrice": 100,
        "extendedPrice": 100,
        "overrideTaxAmount": null,
        "LMIEntity": "LogMeIn US"
    },
    {
        "taxes": [
            {
                "taxType": "GST_IN",
                "taxAmount": 0,
                "taxRate": 0
            }
        ],
        "productFamily": "GoToMeeting",
        "productKey": "G2M_Pro",
        "referenceProductKey": null,
        "taxCode": "C910",
        "quantity": 20,
        "unitPrice": 49,
        "extendedPrice": 980,
        "overrideTaxAmount": null,
        "LMIEntity": "LogMeIn US"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Try Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

Comment: cool, and what have you tried? Can you show some attempts you've made? or some code that is not working

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
 JsonNode jsonObj = mapper.readTree(plain_jsondata);
 String totalTax= jsonObj.get("totalTax");
```

Create a `JsonNode` object and use `.get("key")` to read the value.

Both classes are part of `Jackson` lib `(com.fasterxml.jackson)`.

For nested items, first read and store parent and then do the same on parent.

Comment: what i have to pass as plain_jsondata, is it string of response or ValidatableResponse response, I have validatableResponse and i need to validate that taxType and TaxAmount

Comment: variable containing the json string.

Comment: Please find the below ValidatableResponse

Comment: Just pass the json string you have posted.

Comment: I have written code like below ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
     org.apache.htrace.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode jsonObj = mapper.readTree(extractResponse.body().asString());
     org.apache.htrace.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode totalType= jsonObj.get("taxType");
     System.out.println("tax type= "+totalType);
  I am getting tax type= null

Comment: `taxType` is not in parent node. Read items array first ` jsonObj.get("items")[0].get("taxes")[0].taxType`  this will return for first item.